# Freeform form on busy homepage kills the DB

Tags: solspace-freeform

just used freeform on a large ecommerce site in a dropdown header contact form. Shortly after we went live with it, it killed the db.

We are seeing:

> tail -5000000 /var/ | grep exp_freeform_fields | awk ' { print $1, $2, $3 } ' | cut -d: -f1,2 | sort | uniq -c

happen for every visit:

```
  1 Jun 10 11:38
  1 Jun 10 11:39
  5 Jun 10 11:40
  2 Jun 10 11:42
  1 Jun 10 11:43
  2 Jun 10 11:44
  3 Jun 10 11:45
  1 Jun 10 11:46
  2 Jun 10 11:47
  1 Jun 10 11:48
  1 Jun 10 11:50
  2 Jun 10 11:52
```

This seems to happen with every visit. Is this standard behavior?

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: What is it doing thats killing the DB? can you log into mysql and run `show full processlist` when it is hanging? This will clue us into what query is causing the killing specifically...

Comment: And what free form version are you using? They made big schema changes between 3 and 4.

Comment: ^^ this, and also ExpressionEngine version won't go amiss!

Comment: Every time you load a form it has to fetch which fields belong to it so you can get settings, etc.

These are very simple select queries, though. You would have to have 1000s of fields for this to be a huge issue.

How are you determining that it's those queries that are killing the DB? Your code print out only shows that its being called, but nothing else. Are you using ExpressionEngines query and log output to see how long each query and tag is taking to process?